# AES GCM IV/nonce usage

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, aes-gcm

I'm implementing AES GCM encryption in a WCF project.
After reading and searching I found this [example](https://gist.github.com/jbtule/4336842) (the first class, AESGCM), which seems so be well written and updated.

As I understand it's of high importance that the nonce will be unique as possible, and want to make sure I understand the way this class works.

When I've used IV in the past, in CBC mode, it was necessary to save it for future decryption, but in the example attached I see that the IV (nonce) is not saved.

My question is does the nonce part of the Cipher Text and extracted using:

```
cipherReader.ReadBytes(NonceBitSize / 8)
```

Or am I missing something and the IV/nonce should be saved?

Also - doesn't GCM require the use of salt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the linked piece of code the nonce is prepended to the cipher text. It is therefore recoverable. Losing the nonce means losing data.

In the comments I saw a dangerous idea: Not generating the nonce in a cryptographically secure way. That's not a good idea because you risk colliding nonces that way. It needlessly weakens security.

Comment: Isn't the usual distinction between IVs and Nonce's that an IV should be cryptographically secure but the only requirement for nonces be that you don't reuse them? I.e. Just taking the next number in a sequence, where you know the sequence doesn't repeat, is sufficient for the security proofs for algorithms using nonces.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever this is true. But the comment proposed using a weak RNG, supposedly with a small internal state. For example, two `System.Random` instances will have the same seed and output with about 1/int.MaxValue probability. This would destroy security because an attacker can just try all int.MaxValue possible seeds. Therefore, I recommend: Use a cryptographically strong RNG if you can at all help it.

Comment: Besides, CodesInChaos already mentioned this in the comments as well, and you ignore Codes at your peril :)

Comment: Thanks. Does replacing the relevant code with the following will generate a better result?
RandomNumberGenerator rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

byte[] nonce = new byte[NonceBitSize / 8];

rng.GetBytes(nonce);

Comment: Yes. Don't forget to dispose.

Comment: Thanks, I will wrap it with using :)